# zones api request empty

Tags: php, cdn, netdna-api

I using netdna api. Api is the login process.

```
$api = new NetDNA("xxx","yyyy","zzzz"); // success
```

But.

```
$ret = $api->delete('/zones/pull.json/99999/cache?file=/'.$fileurl);
print_r($ret); // is empty and dont change this file in cdn
```

My ip add whitelist and i checked the key information.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hey @hamideyuce I will get answered for you asap.

Comment: After you run this can you pastebin the results to `curl -I http://cdn.example.com/yourfile` Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a developer at NetDNA and was working over your code:

Our module will automatically handle creating query_strings in the OAuth request as well as adding the parameters into the body of the request, so you should restructure your request to pass the filename as a second parameter to the delete method.

Here's the update to make to your code:

```
$ret = $api->delete("/zones/pull.json/99999/cache", array('file' => '/'.$fileurl);
```

Sorry we didn't have a good example of this in our sample code, updating now.